# Flutter API Request BadState response

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html

I am currently trying to implement an API request with flutter. I have implemented the resuest in Postman and tried all the data. The result was successful. Then I tried to implement this request in my programme. However, I have a problem here, which is why I always get the ResponseCode 400. However, I can no longer explain why. I am using the [FatSecret API](https://platform.fatsecret.com/docs/guides/authentication/oauth2#call-api) here.

The code I used for this request requires an Authorisation Header according to the documentation. This consists of the clientID and the clientSecret. The body also contains "grant_type": "client_credentials" and "scope": "premier".

```
class FatSecretAPI extends ConsumerWidget {
  const FatSecretAPI({super.key});

final String clientId = "...";
final String clientSecret = "...";

  Future<FatSecretToken> fetchAccesToken() async {
    final response = await http
        .post(Uri.parse("https://oauth.fatsecret.com/connect/token"),
        body: {
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
      "scope": "premier"
    }, headers: {
           HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic ${base64.encode(utf8.encode('$clientId:$clientSecret'))};"
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var object = FatSecretToken.fromJson(
          jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
      print(object.accessToken);
      return object;
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw Exception("Failed to load token");
    }
  }

  Future<void> loadToken(WidgetRef ref) async {
    final token = await fetchAccesToken();
    ref.read(accesTokenProvider.notifier).state = token.accessToken;
  }
}

class FatSecretToken {
  final String accessToken;
  final String tokenType;
  final int expiresIn;

  FatSecretToken(
      {required this.accessToken,
      required this.tokenType,
      required this.expiresIn});

  factory FatSecretToken.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return FatSecretToken(
      accessToken: json['access_token'],
      tokenType: json['token_type'],
      expiresIn: json['expires_in'],
    );
  }
}
```

A response in Json format should actually appear here, which contains information about the accesToken and the token type.

Comment: I can't understand what your question is? Perhaps your problem is that you are sending a token, comment out the line `HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic $` ..  You haven’t received the token yet, why send it?

Comment: I have to use some kind of login data to recieve a Token. this token I can use than to acces the whole api. The thing With the acces Token is that it is only available 24Hours.

Comment: I tested with Postman and of course get an error (400) because I don't have a valid client id/secret pair. Of note is that even though I got a 400 I received a body (in Postman) with more details of my error ("invalid client" - not a surprise). Can you test in Postman and see if you can get it to work there first? What error do you see there? If it works, update the question with your redacted working request.

Comment: @RichardHeap I already tried it in Postman and there i fully got it to work, with no problems. same information an i even checked if the `base64.encode(utf8.encode())` gave me the same result for the headder as the postman headder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the whole thing and this is how it works. Probably because of the ; in the auth header. This way it is also more readable and easily customisable for other purposes. You should also outsource the secrets so that they are more secure.

```
Future<FatSecretToken> getToken() async {
    final basicAuth =
        'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$clientId:$clientSecret'));

    final headers = <String, String>{
      'Authorization': basicAuth,
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };

    final body = <String, String>{
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
      'scope': 'premier barcode',
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://oauth.fatsecret.com/connect/token'),
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final object = FatSecretToken.fromJson(
          jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>,
      );
      return object;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get token: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is ";" It looks like.

You should update the 'headers' section as follows:

```
 headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
        "Basic ${base64.encode(utf8.encode('$clientId:$clientSecret'))}"
  },
```

Additionally, the "scope" value must be "basic"

Comment: I think the scope can be basic as well as premier and more. It depends on which API plan you pay for or own.